# RabbitMQ Best Practices for High Availability on Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine, high-availability, message-bus

I'm planning to deploy RabbitMQ on Kubernetes Engine Cluster. I see there are two kinds of location types i.e. 1. Region 2. Zone
Could someone help me understand what kind of benefits I can think of respective to each location types? I believe having multi-zone set up 
could help enhancing the network throughout. While multi-region set up can ensure an undisputed service even if in case of regional failure events. Is this understanding correct? I'm looking at relevant justifications to choose a location type. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm planning to deploy RabbitMQ on Kubernetes Engine Cluster. I see there are two kinds of location types:
>
> 1. Region
> 2. Zone
>
> Could someone help me understand what kind of benefits I can think of respective to each location types?

A *zone* (Availability Zone) is typically a Datacenter.

A *region* is multiple zones located in the same geographical region. When deploying a "cluster" to a region, you typically have a VPC (Virtual private cloud) network spanning over 3 datacenters and you spread your components to those zones/datacenters. The idea is that you should be *fault tolerant* to a failure of a whole _datacenter, while still have relatively low latency within your system.

> While multi-region set up can ensure an undisputed service even if in case of regional failure events. Is this understanding correct? I'm looking at relevant justifications to choose a location type.

When using multiple regions, e.g. in different parts of the world, this is typically done to be *near the customer*, e.g. to provide lower latency. CDN services is distributed to multiple geographical locations for the same reason. When deploying a service to multiple regions, communications between regions is typically done with asynchronous protocols, e.g. message queues, since latency may be too large for synchronous communication.